# Compiler compiling external includes

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-construction, include

I have a little problem in my project. I have build static library(e.g. test.lib) . Included it into my binary project linker and included `#include "test.h"` into `stdafx.h`. But when binary starts to build, C error occurs on `CSomeObject` test:

> "error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'test'".

What could be wrong? I have also included to my binary project `CSomeObject.h`? Also maybe someone could explain how compiler works with includes? Thnx in advance :)

Comment: Maybe you can post some code?

Comment: NOTE: Thanks to everyone! Solved the problem, with swapping includes. I mean include order must be correct.

Comment: @faya - that's an indication that the one header with a dependency on the other should include the other header itself. There are some who might disagree (thinking it's wasteful), but I'd argue that having to track down problems like you ran into is even more wasteful.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're not including everything that needs to be included or you have a incorrectly formed class/struct declaration.

Sometimes this type of error is generated because an identifier right before `test` is something the compiler knows nothing about, so it's treating the statement with `test` as a declaration for that identifier instead of for `test`.  Then when it sees `test` it's a syntax error.

So if you have the line:

```
CSomeObject test;
```

but the compiler doesn't know anything about `CSomeObject`, you'll get the error you're seeing.

You'll also see the problem with something like the following:

```
class CSomeObject {

    // ...

} // there's a missing semi-colon here

CSomeObject test;
```

because what's happening is that the second CSomeObject is an instance of `class CSomeObject`, and `test is a spurious syntax error.

To by syntactically correct, what that should look like is:

```
class CSomeObject {

    // ...

};  // note the semi-colon...

CSomeObject test;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your CSomeObject class missing a ";" at the end of the class declaration, i.e. after the final closing brace ("}") in the header file?